# Custom Icons for Outlook 2016 Ribbon + as distributable package

Tags: icons, microsoft-outlook-2016, ribbon

I wrote a VBA macro for Outlook 2016, and now I would like to add a custom icon and add this to the ribbon to run it.
I've found various post on the net, addressing either older version of Outlook, resulting in instructions I cannot follow. Or explanation how to do this for Excel and other Office applications, but not outlook, resulting again in instructions, which cannot be followed for Outlook.

The instruction are e.g.:

- https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/ribbon_custom_icons.html
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2017
- [How to use my custom icon in the MS Office 2016 Quick Access Toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1052557/how-to-use-my-custom-icon-in-the-ms-office-2016-quick-access-toolbar)

What I don't get is:

1. How can I reference a custom icon, which is a *.png-file on my drive within the RibbonXML?
2. Once I have the configuration of VBA-macro-collection and custom ribbon design ready: export the whole custom configuration into a config file, which my colleagues can import